# Recurrence relation of distances between $n$-dimensional curves

Tags: recurrence-relations, analytic-geometry

I have a problem involving recurrence and euclidean distances in $n$-dimensional curves.

Given the sequence of curves in $\mathbb{R}^n:$

$\{ x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+\cdots + x_{n}^2 = 1, x_{1}^4+x_{2}^4+\cdots + x_{n}^4 = 1, \ldots, x_{1}^{2k}+x_{2}^{2k}+\cdots + x_{n}^{2k} = 1, \ldots \},$

and $d_{k}$ the maximum distance between the origin $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ and each curve.

Does exist a recurrence relation $d_k = f(d_{k-1})$ for all $k > 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d_1=1$as that is a sphere. For higher exponents, the maximum distance comes when all the variables are equal, when all the $x_i=r_m$ with  $nr_m^{2m}=1$.  Then $r_m=\sqrt[2m]{\frac 1n}=n^{\frac {-1}{2m}}$ and the distance is $d_m=\sqrt{nr_m^2}=n^{\frac 12 -\frac{1}{2m}}$

Comment: I am not sure. For $n = 2$, we can see by simulations that $d_2 > 1$, which is different from your expression.

Comment: Yes, I got confused between the coordinate and the distance.  Fixed.  Now if $m \to \infty, r_m\to 1, d_m \to \sqrt n$, which it should.

Comment: Thus, we have the recurrence relation: $d_k = d_{k-1}n^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)}$. Thank you for the help. :)